# unable to download file on Jupyter lab

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, jupyter-lab

Today I tried to download file on Jupyter Lab. I wrote the following code and tried to run：

```
import pandas as pd;
df=%sql select * from xxxx;
table=df.DataFrame();
table.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False);
```

I ran the code and the generated files 'output.xlsx' were displayed in the directory on the left side of the screen. **Since I work in a company, Jupyter Lab's storage resources are configured by the company and are not on my personal computer.** The company should have set up a ban on downloading JupyterLab files.

So when I moved the cursor to 'output.xlsx', right-clicked the mouse, and clicked the 'Download' button, the website prompted me that I cannot download. I also tried to clicked the 'Copy Download Link' button and copy it in the browser, but it still can not be opened. **Jupyter Lab showed '401:Unauthorized'.**

I am very distressed and want to export the excel file to my own computer. I don’t know any way to solve this problem. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Not following here. It may be a language barrier thing with the statement, "The company should have set up a ban on downloading JupyterLab files." You aren't trying to download a JupyterLab file, but an Excel file. You are though using JupyterLab to do it. So maybe you mean a file from within JupyterLab?  Is there a ban or not? Did you try restarting everything and try again? It wasn't a network glitch or Jupyter's connection timing out? I'm not sure why you cannot ask your company's IT people since they set up JupyterLab's storage resource? ...

Comment: <continued> Alternatively, you could probably convert the Excel file to some sort of bytecode, get it as a string and then paste it into a text editor on your local computer, save the bytcode from your local computer to an Excel file? Or read the binary Excel file as a string using Python/Jupyter and grab that string into your local text editor, and save it from in your text editor as `.xls`? But ultimately you just postponing dealing with  file download being a painful experience of acrobatics.

Comment: This is an issue with your "company" policy / permissions, which has little to do with python.

Comment: The HTTP response status code 401 Unauthorized indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource. If you encounter this error, it typically means you need to provide the correct credentials (such as a username and password or API key) to access the resource.